# Jenkins reports multiple busy gradle daemons on agent, but gradle on agent reports no daemons at all running

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I'm running a java test suite on a windows jenkins agent with gradle

When it's running, the jenkins master is reporting this

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 84 busy and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

Here's the command it's running

```
cmd.exe /C "C:\development\jenkins\apppath\gradlew.bat -DenvName=testserver -DenvDriver=ie -PenvName=testserver -PenvDriver=ie regression && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
```

The number of busy gradle daemons keeps increasing, and I think is affecting the performance of the tests, they keep taking longer and longer.

If I go onto the windows slave and run

```
C:\development\jenkins\apppath\gradlew.bat --status
```

It shows as 0 gradle daemons running or busy.

I need to be able to stop all those busy daemons.

Anyone got any ideas how to achieve this?

I've tried restarting the jenkins agent and the master, to no avail.

I've also tried running the following command on the windows agent, still no luck

```
WMIC PROCESS where "Name like 'java%' AND CommandLine like '%GradleDaemon%'" Call Terminate
```